# socket recv() is not returning in Python

Tags: python

I was writing an echo server but recv() does not return while the sender process is alive. If I use one recv() call instead of my recvall() function, it is returning and working. Please let me know what is wrong with recvall() function..

Server:

```
import socket
def recvall(skt):
    msg_total = b""
    while True:
        msg = skt.recv(1024)
        if not msg: break
        msg_total += msg
    return msg_total
def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(("localhost",3333))
    s.listen()
    conn,addr = s.accept()
    # data = conn.recv(1024) <= this recv() is not blocking
    data = recvall(conn)
    conn.sendall(data)
main()
```

Client:

```
import socket
def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("localhost",3333))
    msg = ("a" * 10).encode()
    s.sendall(msg)
    rsp = s.recv(1024)
main()
```

Comment: `recv` only returns an empty bytes object when the socket receive channel has been shut down. The server's recvall would only complete if the client does the shutdown. The solution depends on what you want this code to do. If its just an echo server, just do a bunch of recv / send in a loop. If the client only has one thing to send, have it shutdown the channel after its sendall. if you want a long term conversation, you'll need some way to delimit messages in your protocol.

Comment: thank you. These server and client have a long term conversation and every message has a different size. I guess the sender needs to tell the  receiver how many bytes it sends?

Comment: Yes, that's one of several ways to do it. The easiest is to use something that already knows how to do this stuff. A REST app, for instance, uses HTTP. I like zeromq but I don't know what it's current status is. You could also choose an end sentinel, perhaps a newline or even a NUL. Or, as you say, some sort of header that tells you the size. Maybe even the XMLRPC module.